# Pythonモジュールの階層構造図を書きたい

Tags: python

## Pythonでモジュールの依存関係図を描きたい

本家Stack Overflowで次のような記事を見つけたのですが、
[Python dependencies inside a package - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20829697/python-dependencies-inside-a-package/20839064#20839064)

3種類ツールがあって、snakefoodなら描ける図の粒度を変えたりできる、ということまではわかっています。
pycallgraph, snakefood, modulegraphのインストールはできました。

しかし、ドキュメントを読んでも、どうやって使っていいのかがイマイチぴんときません。
pycallgraphは次のようにやればいいのですが、

```
import pycallgraph
pycallgraph.start_trace()
 # process
pycallgraph.make_dot_graph('test.png')
```

僕がやりたいのは、自分のコードのプロファイリングではなく、Pythonのパッケージ(gensimやその他の)の全体像の把握です。どういう設計になっているのかを俯瞰したいのです。
それはどのようにすれば実現できるでしょうか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Generating Python Module Dependency Graphs](http://www.tarind.com/depgraph.html) が参考になりそうです。この記事の実行例を参考にして、`gensim` モジュールを対象に実行してみました。

```
$ echo 'import gensim' |
  python py2depgraph.py /dev/stdin |
  python depgraph2dot.py |
  dot -T png -o gensim_dep.png
```

最後の `dot` コマンドは `graphviz` パッケージに含まれているコマンドです。

ただ、こちらの実行環境は以下の通りなのですが、

```
      OS: Linux 4.4.0
  Distro: Ubuntu 16.04
  Python: 2.7.11
graphviz: 2.38
```

`py2depgraph.py` の実行時にエラーが発生しますので、以下の変更を施しています。

```
--- py2depgraph.py.org
+++ py2depgraph.py
@@ -39,7 +39,7 @@

     def import_module(self,partnam,fqname,parent):
         r = modulefinder.ModuleFinder.import_module(self,partnam,fqname,parent)
-        if r is not None:
+        if r is not None and self._last_caller is not None:
             self._depgraph.setdefault(self._last_caller.__name__,{})[r.__name__] = 1
         return r
```

出力される `gensim_dep.png` ですが、、サイズが巨大です。

```
$ identify gensim_dep.png
  gensim_dep.png PNG 32767x2789 8-bit sRGB 27.14MB
```

以下は一部分だけを抽出したものです。

[image: gensim_dep_crop.png]

これでは実用的とは言えませんので、例えば `py2depgraph.py` の出力をフィルタリングするなどの処理が必要かと思います。